# Twitter log in pop up window blocked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter, popup

I have a twitter autentication on my angularjs web site. The problem I came up with is that when I press "Sign in using twitter" the pop up window with twitter signing in content should appear, but this pop up is blocked. Browsing google didn't give any useful results. Here some of my code:

**HTML:**

```
<a ng-show="!user.twitterUserLogged" ng-click="TwitterLogIn()" ... >
<i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.TwitterLogIn = function() {
        if(!$scope.user.twitterUserLogged){

            TwitterTweetManager.getToken().then(function(token) {
                $scope.user.TwitterToken = token;
                var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=',
                    params = 'location=0,status=0,width=800,height=600';

                var twitter_window = window.open(url + $scope.user.TwitterToken.oauth_token,"twitter_window",params);

                //if (twitter_window) {
                    var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
                        if (twitter_window.closed) {
                            window.clearInterval(interval);
                            $scope.TwitterLoginFinish();
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                //}

            });

        }

    };
```

Thank You!

Found some information about **window.open()** function. Is is true, that pop-up blockers will allow only **onClick** event? Because I have **ng-click** in my case. Could it be the core of a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem is. It was about asynchronous event on my ng-click. I was getting a token from server on my click event, in this case pop-up blockers will block your popping window. So now I'm getting a token before my event like this:

```
var TwitterToken = TwitterTweetManager.getToken().$object;
```

And my click event:

```
$scope.TwitterLogIn = function() {
        if(!$scope.user.twitterUserLogged && TwitterToken){
                $scope.user.TwitterToken = TwitterToken;
                var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=',
                    params = 'location=0,status=0,width=800,height=600';

                var twitter_window = window.open(url + $scope.user.TwitterToken.oauth_token,"twitter_window",params);

                var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
                    if (twitter_window.closed) {
                        window.clearInterval(interval);
                        $scope.TwitterLoginFinish();
                    }
                }, 1000);
        }
    };
```